# Merge two entities and eliminate null values in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I am trying to merge a master list of customers with another list of customers.  For each customer, I want to keep values from the master input list if the value is already present (not null), otherwise replace it with the corresponding value from the other list.

Something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Card_ID { get; set; }

    public decimal? Cash { get; set; }
}


var masterlist = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer() { ID = 1, Cash = 25 },
    new Customer() { ID = 2, Card_ID = "card2" }
};

var existinglist = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer() { ID = 1, Card_ID = "card1" },
    new Customer() { ID = 2, Card_ID = "card12222222222", Cash = 27 }
};

var mergedlist = (from a in masterlist
                  from b in existinglist
                  where a.ID == b.ID
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = a.ID,
                      Card_ID = (a.Card_ID == null ? b.Card_ID : a.Card_ID),
                      Cash = a.Cash.HasValue ? a.Cash : b.Cash
                  }).ToList();
```

The expected result in the merged list would be like this:

```
{ ID = 1, Card_ID = "card1", Cash = 25 }  
{ ID = 2, Card_ID = "card2", Cash = 27 }
```

Now my point is, I have more than 50 properties in my entity. Is there any easier way to do the merge than hand-coding all 50 conditionals in my `select` clause?

Comment: You can at least shorten it to `Card_ID = a.Card_Id ?? b.Card_Id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a reflection-based helper method to merge the properties of a pair of like objects:

```
public static T Merge<T>(T master, T other) where T : new()
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && !p.GetIndexParameters().Any());

    T result = new T();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(master) ?? prop.GetValue(other);
        prop.SetValue(result, value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, just join the lists using the helper method to do the merge on each pair:

```
var mergedlist = from a in masterlist
                 join b in existinglist 
                 on a.ID equals b.ID
                 select Merge(a, b);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlwXd3